# Session variables doesn't work with background process in php

Tags: php, session-variables, background-process

Does session variables work when using background process?

I have two php scripts - index.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/sand_box/background.php".session_id(), 0, false);
/*
continue the program
*/
```

and the background.php:

```
session_id($argv[1]);
session_start();

sleep(5);

$test = $argvs[1];

$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $test);
fclose($fh);
```

The background process creates the myFile.txt however the session variable doesn't work. I did some other tests and it doesn't work in any case. Anyone knows why?

Is it a limitation of using a background process?

I edited the code, my problem now is that I can't pass any variable as arguments. $argv is always empty.

I finally solved it, register_argc_argv must be enabled on php.ini!

Comment: What do you think about session identifier?

Comment: Honestly never heard of it. Can you o give me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `session_id` to the background script:

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/sand_box/background.php " . session_id(), 0, false);
```

In your background script, you write as the first line:

```
session_id($argv[1]);
session_start();
```

**Edit**: As mentioned by @chris, due to locking you need to be aware that the background script will be waiting for the `index.php` to stop executing.

Answer (score 1):

php usually gets the session id from a cookie or in an http request field. When you execute via command line directly, neither are available to it. So, consider passing the session_id() via a command line arg or environment variable, and then specify it in your spawned script via

```
session_start($the_session_id);
```

next, you need to make sure this other instance of php uses the same config. It could use a different setting for `session_save_path`. check via phpinfo() and adjust as necessary.

And finally, php uses an exclusive locking model on the session file. So, only one process can have a session file for a specific session id open at a time. php normally releases its lock on a session file when it finishes executing the script, but you can make this happen sooner via session_write_close(). If you dont call session_write_close() before spawning the other script, the other script will hang in deadlock when `session_start($the_session_id);` gets called.

but...if the second script doesnt need to modify the session, dont even bother. just pass it the values it needs and forget the session.

Comment: Thank your for your comment! It saved me lots of time. I ran into both issues: 1) In command line, my session.save_path directive was different. Setting the directive in the command before starting the session solves that issue 2) the browser thread acquires an exclusive lock for write on the session so that the command hangs. Invoking session_write_close just before the command works like a charm :). Finally be warned that your CLI PHP version might differ from your HTTP PHP version. This led to differences for me when using openssl_decrypt which had changed in between.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP process invoked by COM will have no knowledge of the user's already established session. Instead you should try passing the session value as an argument to the `background.php` script:

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run(sprintf("C:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/sand_box/background.php %s", $_SESSION['test']) , 0, false);
```

Then in your `background.php` you should be able to access the value via `$argv`:

```
// You should see the session value as the 2nd value in the array
var_dump($argv);

$myFile = 'myFile.txt';
....
```

The above is just a theory as I haven't run it through `COM` before, but should work.

More on argv [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

**-- Update --**

```
session_start();

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");

// Notice the space between background.php and session_id()
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/sand_box/background.php " . session_id(), 0, false);
```

Comment: Looks a good solution but unfortunately doesn't work...or I can't put it to work. I tried to output the data of $argv to the file but it's always empty.

Comment: Are you certain the value you are passing to `background.php` has a value?

Comment: I think so, I edited the code of my question, if you don't mind give a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem was that register_argc_argv was disabled in php.ini.